# Looking Alternative other than Loops

Tags: pandas, performance, dataframe, loops

I have a data frame:

```
df=
year_month  data
(1970,1)     12
(1970,1)     15
(1970,1)      3
(1970,2)     32
(1970,2)     28
```

I want to rank the data per each year_month and divide each rank by the number of data in each group plus 1, where the result is:

```
result=

year_month  data
(1970,1)     0.5
(1970,1)     0.75
(1970,1)     0.25
(1970,2)     0.67
(1970,2)     0.33
```

The explanation: for example row 2: the year_month is (1970,1) and the data is 15. Within (1970,1), the data 15 is ranked as number 3 and divided by 4 (number of data in (1970,1) +1), it results 0.75.

My current approach is by using for loop

```
df_ = []
for ym in yy_mm:
    df1 = df.loc(df.yy_mm == ym)
     n  = df1.shape[0]
    df1 = df1.rank()/n
    df_.append(df1) 

df_result = pd.concat(df)
```

This works, but I am seeking any other way that is more efficient. Using loop is slow, especially it it is a much larger data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four step process

1. get the ranks using `groupby()` then `rank()`
2. get the max ranks within a `groupby()` using `translate()` to get a series
3. calculate *data* as per requirement
4. cleanup workings ...

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""year_month  data
(1970,1)     12
(1970,1)     15
(1970,1)      3
(1970,2)     32
(1970,2)     28"""), sep="\s+")

df2 = df.assign(r=df.groupby("year_month")["data"].rank(),
         mr=lambda dfa: dfa.groupby("year_month")["r"].transform("max"),
         data=lambda dfa: dfa.r / (dfa.mr+1)).drop(columns=["r","mr"])
```

|  | year_month | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | (1970,1) | 0.5 |
| 1 | (1970,1) | 0.75 |
| 2 | (1970,1) | 0.25 |
| 3 | (1970,2) | 0.666667 |
| 4 | (1970,2) | 0.333333 |